# Store additional info when creating new user in IdentityStore in web api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I am building/learning token based authentication with OWIN and I would like to figure out how to insert additional information when creating a new user. The UserManager accepts IdentityUser, but the CreateAsync method only accepts a user name and passowrd. I would like to add at least the email address.  I see that there is a SetEmailAsync method, but that requires a second call. I feel like there should be a single call that allows me to insert other columns, but I am not finding any documentation of how to do this, nor closely related questions in StackOverflow.

Here is the save routine:

```
public class AuthRepository : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly AuthContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

        public AuthRepository()
        {
            _context = new AuthContext();
            _userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(_context));
        }
        public async Task<IdentityUser> FindUserAsync(string userName, string password)
        {
            IdentityUser user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);

            return user;
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> RegisterUserAsync(UserModel userModel)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser
            {
                UserName = userModel.UserName
            };

//save all of this in one call?

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);
            var result1 = await _userManager.SetEmailAsync(userModel.UserName, userModel.EmailAddress);
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<IdentityUser> FindIdentityUserAsync(string userName, string password)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindAsync(userName, password);
            return user;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
            _userManager.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own User class by inheriting IdentityUser class.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

var user = new User
{
    UserName = userModel.UserName,
    Email = userModel.EmailAddress
};

var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, userModel.Password);
```

Make sure you are using User Class instead of IdentityUser.